# How to work around poor text rendering in text backed by a CALayer

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, text-rendering

I have some variable text in an `NSTextField` that renders on a `CALayer` background view. As a `CALayer` does not support sub-pixel aliasing for text rendering of any text on top of it, this text looks rubbish.

A bit of googling reveals the reasons why this is, and that text must be rendered onto an opaque background to have SPA enabled. Rendering onto an opaque background is something I'd like to avoid if at all possible in this case. Is there a better workaround?

I am completely amenable to rendering the text myself into an `NSImage`, if that will help, but I can't find any confirmed reports that it will.

It looks absolutely fine in Interface Builder so I know the secret is somewhere inside this computer just straining to get out.

Comment: Could you post the code used to modify the NSTextView's layer?

Comment: There's very little actual code because I'm mostly doing things in Interface Builder. There's an NSView that controls an NSImageVie

Comment: ...that controls an NSImageView, with a semi-transparent PNG in it. The text sits on top of that.

Comment: Whoever answers this will not only get the 50 reputation, but also my everlasting gratitude. I've been looking for a solution to this for months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround found. Nothing in Quartz can render text with Sub-Pixel Aliasing on top of a transparent background, seemingly. However, you CAN render text to an offscreen bitmap buffer, providing that offscreen bitmap buffer has been created in the correct fashion. The background of this buffer must be opaque.

My view previously had a PNG background that was slightly transparent. I could have simply made this background opaque and rendered to it without problem, but as this view needs to fade in and out, it needed to be CALayer-backed, so the text renders once properly, and then subsequently renders without Sub-Pixel Aliasing.

Here's my code. It seems incredibly verbose, I'd love it if anyone could help me whittle it down. It assumes you have an NSImageView called `_title` and an NSString called `title`.

```
// Create the attributed string
NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: title] autorelease];

NSRange strRange = NSMakeRange(0, [attStr length]);
NSFont *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize: NSSmallControlSize]];

[attStr addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [NSColor whiteColor] range: strRange];
[attStr addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value: font range: strRange];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[paraStyle setAlignment: NSCenterTextAlignment];
[paraStyle setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle];
[attStr addAttribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paraStyle range: strRange];

// Set up the image context
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * [_title frame].size.width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
// These constants are necessary to enable sub-pixel aliasing.
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host;

// Create the memory buffer to be used as the context's workspace
unsigned char *contextBuffer = malloc([_title frame].size.height * [_title frame].size.width * 4);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(contextBuffer, 
                                             [_title frame].size.width, 
                                             [_title frame].size.height, 
                                             bitsPerComponent, 
                                             bytesPerRow, 
                                             colorSpace, 
                                             bitmapInfo);


[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:context flipped:NO]];


CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack));
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, [_title frame].size.width,[_title frame].size.height);
CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attStr);

CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 10.0, 10.0);
CTLineDraw(line, context);
CFRelease(line);

// Create a data provider from the context buffer in memory
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, contextBuffer, bytesPerRow * [_title frame].size.height, NULL);

// Create an image from the data provider
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate ([_title frame].size.width,
                                     [_title frame].size.height,
                                     bitsPerComponent,
                                     bytesPerPixel * 8,
                                     bytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     bitmapInfo,
                                     dataProvider,
                                     NULL,
                                     false,
                                     kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                     );

// Turn it into an NSImage
NSImage *newImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef size: NSZeroSize] autorelease];

CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

free(contextBuffer);

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

[_title setImage: newImage];
```

Comment: Ah - `CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);` is a better way of getting an image out of the context.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out!  I presume the reason it can't blend is because with a transparent background it wouldn't know what to blend with, hence the reason for opaqueness.

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. If it were just a matter of each pixel being ARGB, it could just render it as ARGB and have done with it, but Sub-Pixel Aliasing actually uses ARAGAB, i.e. an alpha value for each colour rather than the pixel as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your limitations are, or why you absolutely have to draw to a layer, but new in [os4.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_1.html) among other things, [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) was ported to iOS from the desktop.  You can probably take advantage of it's advanced type setting features to render glyphs along lines or even arcs and have it do most of the heavy lifting for you.  It is a relatively low-level API, but it is very fast.

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer
        inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CFStringRef string; CTFontRef font;  // assuming these exist

    // Initialize string, font, and context
    CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName };
    CFTypeRef values[] = { font };

    CFDictionaryRef attributes =
        CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**)&keys,
            (const void**)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]),
            &kCFTypeDictionaryCallBacks,
            &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallbacks);

    CFAttributedStringRef attrString =
        CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, string, attributes);
    CFRelease(string);
    CFRelease(attributes);

    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

    // Set text position and draw the line into the graphics context
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 10.0, 10.0);
    CTLineDraw(line, context);
    CFRelease(line);
}
```

Other examples include [CoreTextArcCocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreTextArcCocoa/Listings/CoreTextArcView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007771-CoreTextArcView_m-DontLinkElementID_4) and [CoreTextTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreTextTest/Listings/main_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004140-main_c-DontLinkElementID_3)

Comment: This doesn't work because Core Text has the same limitations as the rest of Quartz. It got me on the right track, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the Original poster did not want to do it, but it was OK for me to have an opaque background...

when you make the layer:

```
    layer.opaque = YES;
```

Then in

```
  - (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context

     [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
      NSGraphicsContext *nscg = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:context flipped:NO];
      [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nscg];

      NSRect ourframe = self.frame;
      // white background enables antialiasing
      [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
      NSRect ourNSFrame = ourframe;
      ourNSFrame.origin = NSZeroPoint;
      NSRectFill(ourNSFrame);

     [sometext drawInRect:ourNSFrame withAttributes:someattrs];

     [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

Answer (score -1):

What are the X, Y positions of the Text once it gets it's variable string filled in?  I had a similar problem for a `UILabel` which was caused by the fact that the XY position of the text were floats. (it was trying to center variable data and the XY vals were half pixels)

I truncated the values and it fixed the blurry text.

Comment: Nope - I had that issue occurring already as the control container view is centred, so half the time on resize it would appear at position x.5 and get screwed up. This is purely text rendering, not positioning.