# Subpixel rendering against color that is not drawn

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584696/catextlayer-subpixel-antialiasing).

`CATextLayer` can only draw text with sub-pixel antialiasing when opaque.

The text is displayed over a tinted image. The image is tinted with a color 90%, which means that I could basically just ignore the few color differences between the image and the tint color, and antialias against the tint.

Now obviously the background of the `CATextLayer` would still have to be transparent.
Unfortunately there is no way to really control sub-pixel AA, you can just disable it or enable it, the rest happens in the background.

I wonder if there is a way to set the anti-alias against a color that is not actually there.
So my question in a sentence:

---

Is there a way to sub-pixel antialias against a color that is never drawn?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as drawing text on that colour, then using that colour as transparency key?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. (It's a bit of a hack, but since there is no answer yet, after one hour, I thought I should probably post it, although it might not be perfect.)

Render black text onto a white background and save it onto an image.

Then you can render that image with blend mode `kCGBlendModeMultiply` using the function `-drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:`.

To draw text in other colors you need a bit more image hackery, but it should be possible too, by using the blend modes creatively.

Comment: I see, nice idea! The background tint and text color are both dynamic, this makes it more difficult. I will try this